# Targeting td elements by colspan attribute (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a page with a bunch of dynamically generated `<td>` elements. I need to target very specific tds on the page. There are quite a bit of elements and so I'm trouble targeting them with nth-child/CSS because of that (there are also alot of elements with the same ID and class selectors so it's proving almost impossible). I've decided to use jQuery instead but can't seem to get that working either. Here's the HTML of the TD I'm trying to target:

```
<td background="v/vspfiles/templates/240/images/Grid_Divider_Horizontal.gif" colspan="5"> 
    <img src="v/vspfiles/templates/240/images/clear1x1.gif" width="3" height="9"> 
</td>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm trying to use:

```
$('td').each(function(){
if ($('td').attr('colspan') == 5) {
    $(this).css({'height':'20px'});
}
});
```

I also tried the same thing but targeted the 'background' attribute. Neither seems to work. I'm basically saying 'if the TD has a colspan of 5, then change it's CSS height to 20px. Am I way off base? I found some documentation that would suggest that this should work but I'm not sure why it's not. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td[colspan='5']").css({height:'20px'});
```

Comment: `each`less: `$("td[colspan='5']").css({height:'20px'});`

Comment: You are correct. I changed it. `.each()` might be useful if they want to do more than just change the height.